# Ionic 5, different files for PWA and native builds

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-routing, ionic-native, ionic5

I want to use the same code-base for my Website and native mobile apps. I am building the native apps using `ionic cordova build <platform>` and deploying the website with `ionic serve --external --prod` inside a docker. I need toh convert the bottom-tab navigation bar on my app to a sidebar on my website. This will require change in routing and HTML files. But all the other files which we are displaying remain the same. So, How do i deploy different files for my website and different ones for my native app on every version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Ionic Platform service

- You could use the [Ionic Platform
  service](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform) to
  determine the platform of the user's current device, then based on
  different platforms, display your desired template using *ngIf
  directive

TS file

> ```
> import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
> @Component({...})
> export class MyPage {
>   is_native: boolean;
>   is_pwa: boolean;
>   constructor(public platform: Platform) {
>      this.is_native = this.platform.is('hybrid');
>      this.is_pwa = this.platform.is('pwa');
>   }
> }
> ```

HTML template

```
    <div #sideMenu *ngIf="is_pwa">...
    </div>
    <div #navBar *ngIf="is_native">...
    </div>
```

## Updated: Shell script

Another way is to replace your template files with different ones using shell scripts.

```
cp src/app/componenets/template.pwa.html src/app/componenets/template.html

ionic serve --external --prod
```

Comment: I tried the ```angular.json``` method and i nothing is getting replaced. I am just getting one error ```String does not match the pattern of "\.(([cm]?j|t)sx?|json)$".``` I don't think Angular build Config is used to replace the html pages. here it says https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19621 "The intention of file replacements is replace files at a TypeScript compiler level."

Comment: Well then you can try to implement file replacements urself using shell scripts

Comment: Yeah, for routing module changes i implemented the angular.json method and replaces them in my custom config and for HTML changes I am checking the platform. Thanks a Bunch